# How to create a subscription in MS Graph Api via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, onedrive, subscription

**Goal**: Get a notification when new folders are added to root

**What I did**: I read [MS official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and tried to set a subscription

function setSubscription()

```
let url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions";
let payload = {
 "changeType": "update",
 "notificationUrl": `https://script.google.com/macros/d/${ScriptApp.getScriptId()}/usercallback`,
 "resource": "me/drive/root",
 "expirationDateTime": "2021-03-31T14:33:45Z"
}
let option = {
 "headers": {
  Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
 },
 "method": "POST",
 "contentType": "application/json",
 "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
 "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
let response = URlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
```

function doPost(e)

```
let output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
output.append(e.queryString);
output.append("200");
return output;
```

But I got an error says "Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request."

I cannot figure out a problem. I tried many notificationUrl patterns that I googled like

```
"notificationUrl": "ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()",
```

but I got the same error or an error "Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter".

And I am not sure the return in doPost(e) is correct.

**What I achieved**: Getting user name, Getting files(items) in OneDrive and Getting subscriptions(of course, no subscriptions displayed)

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible to create subscriptions via Google Apps Script?
2. If it is, what is a problem??

Could someone help me??

Comment: Are you following the instructions from [Notification endpoint validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation)?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, in your script, when you are using `https://script.google.com/macros/d/${ScriptApp.getScriptId()}/usercallback` as the URL of Web Apps, the value of `ScriptApp.getScriptId()` is not the deployment ID. So, for example, how about directly using the deployment ID from URL of Web Apps? By the way, when you redeploy Web Apps, please be careful https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43

Comment: Thank you for replying, Lamblichus. Yes, I read and tried to followed it but I don't know how to response with "HTTP 200 OK", "text/plain" and "validationToken". As I mentioned above, I used ContentService.createTextOutput() and appended "200" and "validationToken" and set mimetype to text then I just return this.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Tanaike. I will try that today! I will reply back again later!!

Comment: @Tanaike I tried but as I get same error "Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request". I think the problem is return in doPost(e) function. I am not sure what I return is follow the [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation).

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when you modify from `return output;` to `return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");`, what result will you obtain? By the way, when you modify the script of Web Apps, please set the latest version of the Google Apps Script project to your deployed Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to the deployed Web Apps with the same URL. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43) Also, as the test, please directly use the URL of Web Apps.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for the gist! I read it and I changed `return output` to `return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");` and got "Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request".

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I'm worry that the API you want to use might not be able to redirect. Because when it accesses to Web Apps, it redirects and the value is returned as the status of `200`. Before the redirect, the status of `302` is returned. Is this related to the reason of your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I am not sure... It can be so I google it !!

Comment: @Tanaike I googled but I could not figure out reasons why it happens. I'm new to Microsoft Graph Api, Google Apps Script and HTTP Get and Post. :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for the late reply. I will do it in Python and find out the reasons.  When I got it, I'll post it here. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Tanaike I made it in Python and I think the reason might be the webhook endpoint. I am not sure still so when I find it out I will answer this by myself.